# Problems with fixed effects for a Mixed Linear Model in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mixed-model, p-value

we want to analyze a Mixed Linear Model. One of the fixed effects (POSITION) has a z-value of 0 and a p-value of 1, despite it should have a significant effect (a graph shows it and it is correct in substance). Do you know how we can fix that issue? If you need further information/pieces of code, I can upload it.

```r
Fixed effects:
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     -9.877e-01  5.706e-01  -1.731   0.0835 .  
Risikodarstellung                1.336e+00  7.688e-01   1.738   0.0822 .  
Icon                            -7.823e-01  7.719e-01  -1.013   0.3108    


Position                        -2.089e-05  1.178e-01   0.000   0.9999   

 
Risikodarstellung:Icon          -8.132e-02  1.106e+00  -0.074   0.9414    
Risikodarstellung:Position       3.277e-01  1.653e-01   1.983   0.0474 *  
Icon:Position                    8.021e-01  1.777e-01   4.513  6.4e-06 ***
Risikodarstellung:Icon:Position -4.486e-01  2.613e-01  -1.717   0.0860 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This is the code for the model:

```r
#Linear mixed model
daten.long <- daten.long %>%
  mutate(Risikodarstellung = recode(Risikodarstellung, "absolut" = 1, "relativ" = 0))
daten.long <- daten.long %>%
  mutate(Szenario = recode(Szenario, "Szenario1Order" = 1, "Szenario2Order" = 2, "Szenario3Order" = 3, "Szenario4Order" = 4, "Szenario5Order" = 5, "Szenario6Order" = 6))
daten.long <- daten.long %>%
  mutate(Icon = recode(Icon, "nein" = 0, "ja" = 1))
daten.long$Ergebnis <- as.numeric(daten.long$Ergebnis)
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.sum"))
cc_full.mod <- glmer(Ergebnis ~ 1 + Risikodarstellung*Icon*Position + (1 |id), data = daten.long, family = binomial,control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
allFit(cc_full.mod) #Da hier der bobyqa-optimizier hier "[OK]" zeigt, haben wir diesen in der oberen Zeile implementiert
summary(cc_full.mod)
```

We have no clue how this could have happened. The code looks okay and the graph shows the effect of Position ...

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest at least adding the code for your model, `summary(your_data$Position)` so we can see what data is there, and perhaps an image of the graph you mention that makes you think `Position` should be significant.

Comment: I would add that you have significant `Position` effects in several interaction terms: `Risikodarstellung:Position` is significant `Icon:Position` is highly significant, and `Risikodarstellung:Icon:Position` is somewhat significant. So my guess would be you are including `Position` in your model 4 times, so perhaps it is not surprising that one of those times (the main effect) isn't significant.

Comment: We can only guess without your data and your model. Perhaps the interactions explain all the apparent differences, or the random effects are confounding.

Comment: Dup of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/623539/problems-with-fixed-effects-or-a-mixed-linear-model

Comment: Reposting my comment from other Q: (1) if your `Szenario` variable isn't included in the model you don't need to the transformation code here - it just clutters things ... (2) it would be helpful to have a reproducible example; (3) I strongly suspect that this is an issue of confounding of fixed effects and that the random effects component is irrelevant, which would simplify the question a little bit - can you try fitting with `glm()` (leaving out the random effect) and see if the phenomenon still occurs?

Comment: thanks for the advice. First, I have shortened the code in order to make the question more concise. I do not really understand what you want me to do according to your (2) and (3) point (especially: "can you try fitting with glm() leaving out the random effect and see if the phenomenon still occurs"). Maybe, you can clarify this for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: (2) A **reproducible example** means an example that we can run ourselves to replicate the problem on our own computers. It's sometimes possible to shorten and simplify your problem, but often with these kinds of problems it is easiest to post a link to the full data (provided they're not sensitive). (3) I'm suggesting that you run this model: `glm(Ergebnis ~ 1 + Risikodarstellung*Icon*Position, data = daten.long, family = binomial)` to see if the results are similar. If they are, you can rule out the possibility that whatever's happening has anything to do with the random effect component.